# pybind11/eigen.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, pybind11

When I try to build [gtsam](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam) on Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8.10 and CMake 3.26.0:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/borglab/gtsam.git
$ cd gtsam
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. -DGTSAM_BUILD_PYTHON=1 -DGTSAM_PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.10 -Dpybind11_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/user/Downloads/gtsam/wrap/pybind11/include
$ make -j$(nproc)
```

I get an error about Pybind not able to find the [eigen header](https://github.com/borglab/gtsam/blob/develop/wrap/pybind11/include/pybind11/eigen.h) file:

```
/home/user/Downloads/gtsam/build/python/gtsam.cpp:12:10: fatal error: pybind11/eigen.h: No such file or directory
   12 | #include <pybind11/eigen.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/gtsam_py.dir/build.make:188: python/CMakeFiles/gtsam_py.dir/gtsam.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:32610: python/CMakeFiles/gtsam_py.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve that?

Comment: I think we need more context for the error message. Is that really the whole error message? If not, show the whole thing. related CMake source: https://github.com/borglab/gtsam/blob/b3635cc6ce8057e04a894870d7ce81e68dd9d707/wrap/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt#L185

Comment: @starball I have added the full Error message, no other errors are encountered.

Comment: oh hello there :P https://github.com/borglab/gtsam/issues/1539

Comment: @starball is it banned to pose the same question twice here and there?

Comment: no it's fine to do that. I personally think even beneficial in some cases. I was just posting the link so other readers here can follow the GitHub issue ticket as well.